# Как делать правильный Rewrite 301 в .htaccess с условиями?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Мужики, помогите настроить в .htaccess редирект всех страниц которые не заканчиваются на "\" или не имеют расширения, соответственно перенаправлять надо на туже самую страницу но с ".html".

Например site-name.com/testpage/test должен вести на site-name.com/testpage/test.html

Совсем не силен в этом деле так как единичная задача.
С меня бутылочка хорошего пива!
Вот мои попытки:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...
RewriteRule ^(.+|\/)$ /$1.html[R=301,L]
```